# How do I know Google Play store apps are authentic and untampered with?

Tags: google-play-store, installation

I use Linux a lot and Android on my phone only for a few things. However I want to install a new app (Signal) for the first time in ages.

Now... when I download and install linux apps I can check and verify authenticity of ISOs and other files with a hashing method (gpg, etc etc) and check the stuff I am installing is verified and kosher etc etc.

But... how do I know that the Signal app I download from Google play is authentic and un-adulterated with the same certainty?

Thanks

Comment: [My answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/105012/59741) on [security.se] is probably related.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it sort of does -- all good tips! -- though I am slightly surprised (though not that much) there is not any more straight up user-friendly ways to do it.